# Decode of UTF-8 String corrupts one string, but not another

Tags: php, string, utf-8

I'm having a very strange error.

I have verified that both my strings are UTF-8 (Checked through mb_check_encoding and mb_detect_encoding) but when I attempt to use utf8_decode on the string, it will return garbage characters to me. In this case, I actually do not need to use utf8_decode and the string will be normal.

The difficulty is that I have customers using UTF-8 databases that I pull strings from and I use utf8_decode to ungarble the strings for PHP. If I don't the space characters will be replaced with Ã . They share the same code to generate the string, but for some reason when I generate it for this other customer, the strings come out all wrong.

Is there a way for me to verify that I will need to use utf8_decode other than the fact that the string is utf 8?

Some Examples:

```
Using utf8_decode for customer 1:
?0,107�per�km
Without utf8_decode for customer 1:
€0,107 per km

Using utf8_decode for customer 2:
$7.00 per km
Without utf8_decode for customer 2:
$7.00Â perÂ km
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: If the databases have inconsistently encoded data it's no wonder you would see something like this.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The customers are international so different encoding standards must be used.

Comment: Why? We 're talking about UTF-8, which can accommodate all of them. Anyway, if their databases are messed up for whatever reason.... I 'm not sure what the question would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mb_detect_encoding` without an informed `detect_order` is no silver bullet, as this would demonstrate:

```
$ php -r 'echo mb_detect_encoding(iconv("utf-8","iso-8859-1","ë"));'
UTF-8
```

Obviously wrong, setting it to strict helps a little bit:

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(mb_detect_encoding(iconv("utf-8","iso-8859-1","ë"),mb_detect_order(),true));'
bool(false)
```

Why is it false? Well, let's examine the possible character sets `mb_detect_encoding()` uses in my configuration:

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(mb_detect_order());'
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(5) "ASCII"
  [1] =>
  string(5) "UTF-8"
}
```

Well, save for `ASCII` & `UTF-8`, no other character set will be detected. Jon has a point though: you can store it all as utf-8, and with the proper database settings, or even only just a correct `character_set_results` in a mysql (which I assume you use...) connection would do the trick to *retrieve* it as utf-8 regardless of how it's stored. However, if this is not an option for whatever reason I can't think of, it's up to *you* to specificy *which character sets* are possible for `mb_detect_order`.

```
$ php -r 'echo mb_detect_encoding(iconv("utf-8","iso-8859-1","ë"),"ASCII,UTF-8,ISO-8859-1,JIS", true);'
ISO-8859-1
```

In short: *you* are responsible for providing a list of possible character sets, and if you already have that kind of information... you can probably *know* the character set (by connection settings, database/table settings, or even just client-configuration, etc.) rather then to try to *detect* it.